# Summing of adjacent cells in a single column that are <>0

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a list of numbers (8780 values in  one column -- a sample is posted below) some of them are <> 0 and some of them are 0.

> List of numbers:
>   0
>   0
>   0
>   0
>   0,127227198
>   0
>   0
>   0,229366036
>   0,174893344
>   0
>   0,247079364
>   0
>   0,508165499
>   0,380252705
>   0,221018177
>   0,703514629
>   0
>   0,49853953
>   0,891621276
>   1,795142292
>   0
>   0
>   0
>   0
>   1,405576577
>   0,965799766
>   0,347987496
>   0,15944612
>   0,087348148
>   0
>   0

For each series of numbers adjacent that are <>0 I want to summarize those cell values and ad the sum in a separate cell in column B. How can I do that? Can I use an some combination of an if function in the B-column?

As you can see the numbers <> 0 appear randomly so I think need some kind of formula that checks if the row before or after is = 0 and if the row after is <> 0 it should start summing the numbers above.

So for instance I want to add the sum of the below numbers into one cell.

```
1,405576577  
0,965799766  
0,347987496  
0,15944612  
0,087348148
```

I really appreciate any help i can get! Hope this became clearer :)

Comment: What series of numbers? Can you add a screen shot or edit your post to show us what the current sheet looks like (even if just the top 2 or 3 rows)?

Comment: So is each series of numbers that you want to sum separated by a 0?

Comment: I have edtied my question. Hope it makes more sense now. Thanks @DaveRook

Comment: What would the sum be? For instance, what do the numbers before the `,` represent? This doesn't seem like excel would think it's a **number**

Comment: @Raystafarian That's the decimal point -- just different regional settings.

Comment: @Excellll ah makes sense, I was thinking they were coordinates whoops

Comment: haha! Yes Excaktly. Sorry i should have changed it. "," is a decimalpoint in Swedish Excel @Raystafarian

Comment: Nah you shouldn't have to change it, my fault. Do you need a function or would a macro work?

Comment: macro would work to, but I am not to famliar with macros so would not be able to change it to much my self

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For original data in `A1:A25`, you can use the following:

In `B1` enter the following array formula by pasting into the formula bar and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MIN(IF($A1:$A$25=0,ROW($A1:$A$25),ROW($A$26)))>ROW($A1:$A$25))*($A1:$A$25))
```

This formula sums the values in A1 and below that occur before the first zero.

In `B2` enter the similar array formula with an extra condition (also using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>):

```
=IF(A1<>0,0,SUMPRODUCT((MIN(IF($A2:$A$25=0,ROW($A2:$A$25),ROW($A$26)))>ROW($A2:$A$25))*($A2:$A$25)))
```

This has a condition to check for a nonzero cell above in column A -- if it is nonzero, 0 will be returned. Otherwise, sum values that occur before the next zero.

Sample:

[image]